# Dcmj2pnm tojpeg patient name missing

Tags: dicom, dcmtk

I am new in Dcmj2pnm . i have succesfully converted a Dcm file to jpg  through commandline  in Win 7 using 
C:\dcmj2pnm.exe  D:\test.dcm D:\test.jpg +oj +Wi 1

But it misses the patient name and organization name  in dcm file to jpeg.

Could you please guide me how to get thease details in to my jpeg file ?

Comment: The documentation does not mention moving any tags to exif. I did a quick test here and no tags where transferred.

Comment: Could you please explain? i am a newbie in this

Comment: JPEG files don't define a standard way of storing patient/org info. How did you expect it to be stored?

Answer (score 1):

dcmj2pnm is not capable of transferring DICOM header data to JPEG header data (which is referred to as EXIF). It is limited to extract and convert the pixel data contained in the DICOM file.

Comment: I want to get some tags in dcm file.So dcmj2pnm is not a good choice right?. any suggestion other tools?

Comment: dcmdump for example to stick with the toolkit of your choice.

Comment: Hi  I want this tags along with jpeg . is there any tool do this through command line ?

Comment: None that I am aware of

Comment: thanks! I have solved this using dcmj2pnm and dcm2xml and  write the required tag to jpg programatically .. Thanks again